# Password_Digest has problems when new columns are added

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I've got a user model for my app, and it has effectively used `has_secure_password` up til this point.  `has_secure_password` necessitates a `password_digest` column, and herein lies my recent problem.

I wanted to create a "role" column of type string that separates admins from users - but after migrating, my `password_digest` got corrupted so that I get an invalid hash error whenever I try to use it in my app.  In mysql everything is fine (the `password_digest` values haven't changed) but in rails console the value returned by `User.first.password_digest` is something along the lines of:

```
\#BigDecimal:59d0c60,'0.0',9(18)
```

Furthermore, unless I change the type of role from string, it gets similarly messed up (although like `password_digest`, it's totally fine in mysql regardless).  Rolling back the migration and getting rid of the "role" column causes `password_digest` to go back to normal as far as rails console is concerned.

What is going on here?

Here's my database schema:
[image: Database schema]

Here's the result of a sql query fed directly to mysql:
[image: MySQL query]

Here's the result of the same query through rails (first time):
[image: Rails query]

Here's the result of the same query through rails (after first time):
[image: Rails query2]

Comment: I don't believe anybody can debug your situation from your description alone... there's just not enough context without seeing some code and table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is getting auto-explained.  See the documentation here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#automatic-explain

Comment: If that's the problem, I'm not sure where to put Base.silence_auto_explain...does it go in a file?

Comment: I think the most important thing to find out here is why auto-explain is getting triggered.  I'm led to believe that something more than just the database schema was changed. I agree with Jim Garrison, there is not enough info for someone to debug your problem.